# Find the cardinality of a unital ring with an interesting property

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(A,+,\cdot)$ be a unital ring with $|A| \ge 4$. If $\forall x,y \in A \setminus \{0,1\}, x\ne y$, we have that either $x^2=y$ or $y^2=x$, find $|A|$.
I didn't make much progress, but I have a hunch that $|A|=4$ since we are given that lower bound. I thought that maybe we should assume that the ring has at least $5$ elements, so we could pick three pairwise distinct elements $x, y, z$, but I didn't seem to reach any contradiction.
I also thought that maybe we may consider the function $f: A \to A, f(x)=x^2$, but I don't know what to do next.
Note: we aren't given that $A$ is finite.

Comment: Suppose $|A|>4$ and pick some $x\in A\backslash\{0,1\}$. Then for every $y\in A$ we have $y\in\{0,1,x,x^2\}$ or $y^2=x$, so there exists some $y\in A$ with $y^2=x$. For the same reason there exists some $z\in A$ with $z^2=y$. Then $z^4=x$ and we have $z\in\{x,x^2\}$ or $z^2=x$. That is, either $x^4=x$, $x^8=x$ or $x^2=x$, respectively. Then $A$ has positive characteristic $n$, and $\varphi(n)$ divides either $3$, $7$ or $1$, respectively. It follows that $n=2$ and so $A$ is an $\Bbb{F}_2$-algebra, and it clearly has no nontrivial idempotents.

Comment: Moreover, for every $x\in A\backslash\{0,1\}$ you then either have $x+1=x^2$ or $(x+1)^2=x$, i.e. $x^2+x+1=0$. (Note that $x+1\in\{0,1\}$ is impossible.) So $\Bbb{F}_2(x)\cong\Bbb{F}_4$ for every $x\in A\backslash\{0,1\}$. Now if $|A|>4$ then we have $x,y\in A$ such that $\Bbb{F}_2(x)\neq\Bbb{F}_2(y)$, but then also $x,y\notin\{0,1\}$, $x\neq y$ and $x^2\neq y$ and $y^2\neq x$, a contradiction. So $|A|=4$.

Answer (score 7):

A partial answer.

Consider $2 \in A$ and $3 \in A$. There are three possibilities:

- $2=3$ — in this case $1=0$ and $A$ is the [zero ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_ring), so $|A|=1$
- $2^2=3$ — thus, again, $1=0$
- $3^2=2$ — that is, $7=0$, so $A$ is an algebra over $\mathbb F_7$ (the field with 7 elements). Consider $x=2 \in A$ and $y=5 \in A$: $2^2=4$ and $5^2=(-2)^2=4$ (remember that we work modulo $7$ here). In particular, $x\neq y$, yet $x^2 \neq y$ and $x \neq y^2$.
- $2=0$
- $3=0$

Thus, we are forced to assume either $2=0$ or $3=0$.

Comment: I think you miss the case $2=0$ or $3=0$. Note that you are assuming that $2,3 \notin \{0,1 \}$.

Comment: I agree with N.S.'s comment. In fact, $A=\mathbb{F}_4$ satisfies the requested property.

Comment: Indeed, thank you a lot. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks! We can easily see that $3=0$ doesn't work. Assume it does. Then for any $x\in A \setminus \{0,1,2\}$ we get that $x^2=2$. We also have that $x+1\in A \setminus \{0,1,2\}$, so $(x+1)^2=2$. From these we obtain that $2x=2$, so $x=1$, which is a contradiction. We are left with $2=0$.